# how to make sub-sections appear on the right side of the Rooms section when hovering the cursor over the Rooms section

Tags: css, menu, navbar, sidebar

I have a sidebar that slides to the right when hovering the cursor, I need that when hovering the cursor over sections that have sub-sections on the right side sub-sections appear as well as the main sidebar

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgzoI.png)

[link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Ilgar-Rzayev/pen/MWxaXRp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="menu">
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8"/>
         <title>Side Menu</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css">
         <style>
            .logo{
            }

            .fa-solid {
            position: relative;
            display: table-cell;
            width: 55px;
            text-align: center;
            top:25px; 
            font-size:20px;
            }
            .main-menu:hover, nav.main-menu.expanded {
            width:250px;
            overflow:hidden;
            opacity:1;
            }
            .main-menu {
            background:#808080;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            bottom:0;
            height:100%;
            left:0;
            width:80px;
            overflow:hidden;
            -webkit-transition:width .2s linear;
            transition:width .2s linear;
            -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
            box-shadow: 1px 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07);
            opacity:1;
            }

            .main-menu li>a {
            position:relative;
            width:400px;
            display:table;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border-spacing:0;
            color:#ffffff;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-decoration:none;
            -webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
            -webkit-transition:all .14s linear;
            transition:all .14s linear;
            font-family: 'Strait', sans-serif;
            }

            .main-menu .nav-text  {
            position:relative;
            display:table-cell;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width:190px;
            height: 65px;
            }

            nav {
            -webkit-user-select:none;
            -moz-user-select:none;
            -ms-user-select:none;
            -o-user-select:none;
            user-select:none;
            }
            nav ul,nav li {
            outline:0;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
            color:#DAA520;
            text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px; 
            }
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    background: #808080;
    width: 200px; /* или другая ширина по вашему выбору */
}

.main-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    display: block;
}
            </style>
      </head>
      <body>
         </div>
         <nav class="main-menu">
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                <a class="logo" href="#">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-burger"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">Menu</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </ul>
            </div>
            <ul>
               <li>                                   
                  <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house"></i>
                  <span class="nav-text">Main</span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>                                 
                  <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-info"></i>
                  <span class="nav-text">About</span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>                                 
                  <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-barcode"></i>
                  <span class="nav-text">Rooms</span>
                  </a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
               </li>
               <li>                                   
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-wine-glass"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">Meal</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>                                 
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-children"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">For children</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>                                 
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-list-check"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">Services</span>
                </a>
             </li>
             <li>                                 
                <a href="/">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-address-book"></i>
                <span class="nav-text">Contacts</span>
                </a>
             </li>
            </ul>
         </nav>      
      </body>
   </html>
```

But my subdivisions appear superimposed on top of the sidebar

Comment: just had a quick look at your codepen and if I change line 19 from `overflow:hidden;` to `overflow:visible;` it seems to work as you want without any obvious problems

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.